# How to debug the code inside the DLL

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-c++, dll

I have a C# program from which I am calling some functions/variables from C++.
The C++ program itself runs fine, and is checked. But, when I build this DLL and use it for C#, there is some bug in the interfacing code that is preventing me to get the correct result in C#.

Most probably, there is some error in export variables/exported functions giving out the results, which I want to check.

My primary question is : How do I debug this DLL, as in by putting breakpoints etc. and following along by seeing the results as we could do for any other program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have source code and debug symbols for the native (C++) DLL, you can check the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" option on the "Debug" tab of the managed (C#) EXE project, and then set breakpoints, inspect variables etc. in the C++ code as usual. You can add the C++ project to the solution, or just open a single C++ source code file and set breakpoints there.

Comment: My C++ project is in the solution, and has all the breakpoints set. I checked `Enable Unmanaged code debugging option` under Debug Tab in C# exe project, but the breakpoints in C++ get disabled when I start debugging ( and on hovering over them, the tooltip message is: `The breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug the DLL, you should work in your C++ environment, put breakpoints in your c++ code, but use the executable generated by c#.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this kind of scenario, is by either using Visual Studio mixed mode debugging (via **devenv /debugexe yourapp.name.exe**  command) or using Windbg + SOS extension (steeper learning curve, but this would show a lot more information, like you type sizes in native and managed code)
To learn how to use Windbg  + SOS, please see Advanced .NET Debugging by Mario Hewardt

Note, that often these kind of issues are caused by 
    1) Incorrectly chosen C# data type to use with C++ APIs
    2) Incorrectly specified / unspecified function calling convention 
    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/05/21/56690.aspx